# Building smarter elements for Final Cut Pro X with Motion 5

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, motion

### Help me not look like an idiot who's schizophrenic about the date.

I am producing a series of videos recorded at a monthly event. The client webcasts the event live and wants to raise awareness of this fact. They also want to document the date on which the footage was recorded. To this end, they have requested a that *both the build in and the build out* include the date in the copy. (Feel free to correct my terminology. I just mean a "slide" at the beginning and at the end.) Here's an example:

> Originally live-streamed... on February 1, 2014.

I created the builds in Motion and set the text field as editable in FCP X and made sure to publish it. I have everything technical working, but I'm afraid that I'm going to forget to change the date on the build out. Is there a way to just input the date once in Final Cut Pro X and have it populate to 2 different Motion-made titles?

Ideally, the date would be like a variable so that it could sit in line. My fantasy would be something like this:

> Originally live-streamed... on $DATE.

with only one input for $DATE. I would also accept

> $DATE

so long as it populated into 2 different Motion-made titles. I could create one text element for the date field and another for the rest of the copy.

Comment: My current "workaround" is to not use placeholder text for the date in the build-out, i.e., "Originally live-streamed to members." instead of "Originally live-streamed to members on MMMMMMM DD, YYYY." That way, if I forget, it's innocuously incomplete, which is better than incorrect, better than living placeholder text, and better than contradicting the . I make the text in the element editable in Final Cut Pro X. When I remember, I add the date to the end. So far I'm 12 for 12 on remembering.